# Can I do Django & Python web development using Xcode 3.2?

Tags: python, django

I'm not sure but I believe that Python is -next to Objective-C- somewhat natural to Mac OSX and the Xcode IDE. I might be wrong. So is it a good idea to use Xcode for Django / Python web development when I'm already a bit familiar with Xcode? Actually I only do iPhone dev with it, but now I need a website and I stumbled over Django / Python. I don't want to "fall back" to PHP again, because just everyone and his dog does that already. Want to give Django / Python a try ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use XCode to program on Django, as it's plain Python 2.x and [XCode is a good tool for Python](http://zovirl.com/2006/07/13/xcode-python/).

Make sure that you learn the [pythonic constructs before trying to make advanced things with Django](http://dougalmatthews.com/articles/2009/dec/14/django-its-just-python/), as you might be trying to bend the framework to do some things that the language already does.

Answer (score 6):

I wouldn't suggest XCode for python/django development - it's another world. An editor may be sufficient. A list of IDEs for python can be found here: [What IDE to use for Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81584/what-ide-to-use-for-python)

Comment: I second this. Last time I tried editing Python in XCode it would almost continually screw up my indentation. Now, this was an early version of XCode, and maybe I was using tabs instead of spaces... but I found it a very bad experience.

Answer (score 2):

I think Eclipse+Pydev Plugin is a good choice!!

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend it even though xcode supports it. The problem is the host of nifty little features which are provided by IDEs like pycharm, eclipse is not present (or atleast not available out of the box) for example inbuilt django support, db integrations, git integration, intellisense, syntax highlighting etc.

I'd definitely recommend PyCharm for Python/Django development.

In fact, why don't you choose it yourself: 
[IDEs supporting Python with their pros n cons](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1l3x94P55qoxqYbq5GosWQ7IonZ4vR-4ZyCaImiVmCSk/pubhtml)